# Expected value of dice game -- Can Wald's equality be used?

Tags: expected-value, dice, stopping-times

This is somewhat related to [Expected payoff of dice game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122166/expected-payoff-of-dice-game/4122171?noredirect=1#comment8525438_4122171), where the problem is:

> You roll a fair $6$-sided die. For each roll, you're paid the face value. The game stops when you roll a $1,2,3$. If you roll a $4,5,6$, you can roll again and keep accumulating payments.

---

Mees's comments states that Wald's equality can not be used to solve this problem because $N$ is not independent of $X_i$, although I don't believe that dependency precludes us from using Wald's equality. But there is something else that concerns me about the application of Wald's equality here.

For all variants of Wald's equality, the $X_i$'s are always IID. For the dice game, I am hesitant to believe they are IID.
The thing is, the game stops if we roll a $1,2,3$. So if we make it to round 2, then that, by definition, means that we tossed a $4,5,6$ in round 1. So based on this, it seems we lose independency and identicalness, and the $X_i$'s are no longer independent nor identical?

In the book where I saw this question from, it states

> Wald's equality can be applied since the problem has clear stopping rules. For each roll, the process has 0.5 probability of stopping. So the stopping time $N$ follows a geometric distribution with $p = 0.5$, and thus $E[N] = 2$. For each toll, the expected face value is $E[X] = 3.5$. The total expected payoff is $E[S_N] = E[X]E[N] = 7$ where $S_N = X_1 + \ldots + X_N$.

But I am hesitant to believe this is valid. I don't believe the $X_i$'s are independent for the reason I stated above. Furthermore, we know that $X_1, \ldots, X_{N-1}$ must be $\in \{4,5,6\}$ otherwise the game would have stopped, and we further know $X_N \in \{1,2,3\}$.

So I think the more appropriate justification would actually be that we can view $Y_1, \ldots, Y_{N-1}$ as IID of a 3-sided dice with faces $4,5,6$, and redefine $S_N = Y_1 + \ldots + Y_{N - 1} + X_N$.

Then I want to apply Wald's equality to $E[Y_1 + \ldots + Y_{N - 1}]$, but now I am unsure if Wald's equality's assumptions are satisfied. If they are, this would give us $E[Y_1]E[N - 1] = 5 * 1 = 5$..
And then we have $E[X_N] = 2$.

So the expected payoff is $E[S_N] = 5 + 2 = 7$. I don't know if my approach is more valid, or if the book's approach is valid.

Overall, I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 2):

If $X_k$ is the $k$-th roll of the dice then all $X_k$ are independent, just note that what happen in a roll doesn't determine what happen in another. You are mixing there the end of the game, what can be seen as a stopping time, and the $X_k$, what are just i.i.d. r.v.

Indeed $\{N=n\}=\{(X_1,\ldots ,X_{n-1})\in A^{n-1}, X_n\in B\}$, for $A:=\{4,5,6\}$ and $B:=\{1,2,3\}$, so $\{N=n\}\in \mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma (X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$ and consequently $N$ is a stopping time by definition. Then a version of Wald's identity can be applied, this version says that if $N$ is a finite stopping time and all $X_k$ are i.i.d. non-negative r.v. with finite mean $m$, then $\operatorname{E}[S_N]=m\operatorname{E}[N]$ where

$$
S_N:=\sum_{k=1}^N X_k
$$

Now suppose that $N=\infty $, this would mean that the game never stop, however the probability of this is zero, so $N$ is a finite stopping time and you can apply the previous version of Wald's identity.

Note: this Wald's identity appear in a problem of the book of Robert Ash of probability and measure.

---

EDIT:  an alternative approach, surely more intuitive, is to use the law of total expectation, that is

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}[S_N]&=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\operatorname{E}[S_N|N=n]\Pr [N=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\operatorname{E}[S_n|N=n]\Pr [N=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{E}[X_k|N=n]\Pr [N=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}(5(n-1)+2)\Pr [N=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}(5(n-1)+2)\left(\frac1{2}\right)^n\\
&=5\sum_{n\geqslant 1}n2^{-n}-3\\
&=5\cdot 2-3\\
&=7
\end{align*}
$$

because

$$
\operatorname{E}[X_k|N=n]=\begin{cases}
5,&\text{ if }k<n\\
2,&\text{ if }k=n\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Are you saying that $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ are also IID?

Comment: @student010101 there each $X_k$ represent a roll of the dice, and yes, they are independent if we want a realistic model of rolling dice. However $N$ is not independent of any $X_k$, and it doesn't need to be to apply the mentioned version of Wald's identity

Comment: I agree with your second sentence, but I am not seeing how they're independent. But I think the bigger issue here is I definitely don't see how they're *identically* distributed when, as you noticed, the first $n - 1$ values can only be in $\{4,5,6\}$ and the last value in $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: @student010101 each $X_k$ is a dice, they can take any value independently of each other, there is not a "last" dice, it is an infinite sequence of dice. Then over this i.i.d. sequence we define the stopping time $N$ that represent the length of a game. You are mixing the dice themselves with the game we define using these dice.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and I agree, because each toss of the die is memoryless, so they should all be IID, 
but, at the same time I'm still stuck on why what you're saying is more valid than my initial thought. It still makes sense in my head, but it obviously contradicts the memoryless nature of the tosses, which also makes perfect sense

Comment: Let me clarify a couple things. (1) Are you saying that $X_1, \ldots, X_{N - 1}$ are uniformly distributed in $\{4,5,6\}$? (2) Are you saying that $X_N$ is uniformly distributed in $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: @student010101 each $X_k$ is uniformly distributed in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, or at least we suppose it if they are fair dice, but I dont know how is distributed $X_N$. $X_N$ is defined by $X_N=X_n$ when $N=n$, I dont did any calculations to see how it is distributed

Comment: But in your answer, don't you define that $\{N=n\}=\{(X_1,\ldots ,X_{n-1})\in A^{n-1}, X_n\in B\}$, for $A:=\{4,5,6\}$ and $B:=\{1,2,3\}$, which seems to suggest that $\{X\}_{i = 1, \ldots, n - 1}$ are uniformly distributed in $\{4,5,6\}$ instead of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Comment: @student010101 there $\{N=n\}$ is an event, the event that means "the game end at the $n$-th roll", it is a shorthand for $\{\omega \in \Omega : N(\omega )=n\}$, where $\Omega $ is the abstract domain where all r.v. are defined. Go to the chat if you want discuss this, it will be better