# Probability involving infinite rounds of rolling a die?

Tags: probability

You are playing a fair die game with 'n' die rolls. You roll the die for the first time as a preparatory roll, and the result is P. Then, if you ever roll a die more than or equal to this value P you instantly cash out, and the game ends. If not, you keep rolling and take the sum of all previous successful rolls(result smaller than P). What would the expected gain be?

My major question is that wouldn't this result in possible infinite rounds? Let's say rolling a 6  in the first place. I have no clue on this one, please help.

Comment: So if you roll, for example, (3,1,1,1,1,6) the payout is 4?

Comment: yes, based on my understanding

Answer (score 3):

Since the question strongly depends on $P$, let's assume that $P>1$ is known (for $P=1$, the game ends on the next round). The possibilities to cash out are $P,P+1,...,6$ and in total there are $7-P$ possibilities. So the probability of ending the game in each turn is $\tfrac{7-P}{6}$.

Let $N$ be the number of rounds. $N$ is geometric with the above probability, so the expected number of rounds is $\tfrac{6}{7-P}$.

In each round where you didn't cash out, the expected payoff is $\tfrac{1+2...+P-1}{P-1}=\tfrac{P}{2}$. So the total payoff (assuming you don't get paid for the over the $P$ roll) is $(\tfrac{6}{7-P}-1)\cdot\tfrac{P}{2}=\tfrac{P(P-1)}{2(7-P)}$ (see [Expected payoff of dice game](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4122166/731237) for details how exactly to calculate it)

Now it is left to get rid of this $P$. Well, according to the law of total probability, we can simply sum these expressions for each $P$ times the probability of having it, so

$$\sum\limits_{P=2}^6 \tfrac{P(P-1)}{2(7-P)}\cdot \tfrac{1}{6}=7.9$$